# Objective-C ARC and __weak for NSString

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

```
NSString __weak *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"First Name: %@", @"Braj"];
NSLog(@"string:%@", string);


NSString __weak *string2=@"Hello";
NSLog(@"string:%@", string2);

NSString __weak *string3 =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Braj"];
NSLog(@"string:%@",string3);
```

Here, first string gives output null and other two string objects gives ans as Hello and Braj respectively. 
I am confused here how to deal __weak reference.

Answer (score 1):

"weak" means the pointer variable doesn't hold a reference to the object, so the pointer allows the object to be deallocated. When that happens, the pointer is set to nil.

So the first NSLog does what you should expect. There is no strong reference to the object, so it becomes nil immediately.

In the second case, you have a string literal. String literals are different: They actually *never* go away. They are created using some clever trickery which means no memory would be saved if they were deallocated.

The third case: [[NSString alloc] initWithString:aString] is clever. It doesn't actually allocate a new string if it isn't necessary! If aString is an immutable string, then the result is aString and not a new object. You passed a string literal to it, so the result is that string literal. Back to case 2 :-)

weak references can become nil when someone else releases the last strong reference to an object. But your code never knows who might hold a strong reference (behind the scenes), so you can never rely on a weak reference becoming nil.

Comment: Thanks!! It adds a value to me.

Comment: In third case, If i don't pass Literal and I pass string variable to it. In that case also, string3 doesn't become nil.